# How can i open steam/etc without it opening a cmd?

Tags: batch-file, steam

I am new to coding and I wrote a batch program to try to make steam, origin, uplay and Battle.net run when I launch this program. However it only launches their CMDs and I think I have done something wrong. Here is my program:

```
@echo off
echo starting steam.exe ...
start "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\Steam.exe"
timeout 2
echo starting battle.net.exe ...
start "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\Steam.exe"
timeout 2
echo starting origin.exe ...
start "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\Steam.exe"
timeout 2
echo starting uplay.exe ...
start "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\Steam.exe"
pause
```

Comment: Are you sureyou want to start exactly the same command line four times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with :

```
@echo off
echo starting steam.exe ...
start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\Steam.exe"
timeout 2
```

If put in quotes the first argument is [the title](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html) so you can put empty quotes as a first argument.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the following code!

```
echo off
color 0b
cls
echo Starting Steam...
start C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\Steam.exe
timeout 2
echo Starting battle.net.exe
start C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\Steam.exe
timeout 2
echo Starting Origin...
start C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\Steam.exe
timeout 2
echo Starting UPlay...
start C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\Steam.exe
exit
```

You **DO NOT** Use quotes in the **START** command, as it will not recognize the quotes and just open a elevated CMD Prompt. It is not needed also.